# How to terminate early in Golang Walk?

Tags: go

What's the idiomatic way, if possible, of having Go's `filepath.Walk` return early?

I'm writing a function to find a nested directory of a given name. Using `filepath.Walk` I can't see a way of terminating the tree-walking as soon as I find the first match.

```
func (*RecursiveFinder) Find(needle string, haystack string) (result string, err error) {
    filepath.Walk(haystack, func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, errIn error) (errOut error) {
        fmt.Println(path)

        if fi.Name() == needle {
            fmt.Println("Found " + path)
            result = path
            return nil
        }

        return
    })

    return
}
```

Comment: why not return an error and make the walk stop? you can return `io.EOF` to make sure there was no other error.

Comment: expanding as an answer...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should return an error from your walkfunc. To make sure no real error has been returned, you can just use a known error, like `io.EOF`.

```
func Find(needle string, haystack string) (result string, err error) {

    err = filepath.Walk(haystack, 
      filepath.WalkFunc(func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, errIn error) error {
        fmt.Println(path)

        if fi.Name() == needle {
            fmt.Println("Found " + path)
            result = path
            return io.EOF
        }

        return nil
    }))

    if err == io.EOF {
        err = nil
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I discovered `filepath.SkipDir()` after posting, which the docs mention. Do you know if there's any difference between returning `io.EOF` and `SkipDir()`?

Comment: SkipDir() will not stop the walk, but will jump to the next directory. If it's not a recursive walk the effect will be the same, but I think it's better to return another error. from TFM: `If an error is returned, processing stops. The sole exception is when the function returns the special value SkipDir. If the function returns SkipDir when invoked on a directory, Walk skips the directory's contents entirely. If the function returns SkipDir when invoked on a non-directory file, Walk skips the remaining files in the containing directory`

Comment: Don't use that anymore, use `return filepath.SkipDir` and `return filepath.SkipAll` as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when they were introduced, but the `filepath` package now has two constants, `filepath.SkipDir` and `filepath.SkipAll`. These can be used as return values to change the behavior of the `filepath.Walk` or `filepath.WalkDir` functions.

#### As of the posting of this answer, they are defined as

```golang
var SkipDir error = fs.SkipDir
```

> **SkipDir** is used as a return value from WalkFuncs to indicate that the directory named in the call is to be skipped. It is not returned as an error by any function.

```golang
var SkipAll error = fs.SkipAll
```

> **SkipAll** is used as a return value from WalkFuncs to indicate that all remaining files and directories are to be skipped. It is not returned as an error by any function.

Additionally, the `filepath.Walk` and `filepath.WalkDir` functions include this section in their documentation:

> The error result returned by the function controls how Walk continues. If the function returns the special value SkipDir, Walk skips the current directory (path if info.IsDir() is true, otherwise path's parent directory). If the function returns the special value SkipAll, Walk skips all remaining files and directories. Otherwise, if the function returns a non-nil error, Walk stops entirely and returns that error.
>
> The err argument reports an error related to path, signaling that Walk will not walk into that directory. The function can decide how to handle that error; as described earlier, returning the error will cause Walk to stop walking the entire tree.

---

See https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#pkg-constants

Comment: This is the way to do it nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [errors.New](//golang.org/pkg/errors#New) to define your own error:

```
import (
   "errors"
   "os"
   "path/filepath"
)

var stopWalk = errors.New("stop walking")

func find(name, root string) (string, error) {
   var spath string
   e := filepath.Walk(root, func (path string, info os.FileInfo, e error) error {
      if info.Name() == name {
         spath = path
         return stopWalk
      }
      return e
   })
   if e == stopWalk {
      return spath, nil
   }
   return "", e
}
```

Or you can use [filepath.Glob](//golang.org/pkg/path/filepath#Glob):

```
import "path/filepath"

func find(pattern string) (string, error) {
   paths, e := filepath.Glob(pattern)
   if paths == nil { return "", e }
   return paths[0], nil
}
```